# Why ajax doesn't export my input to a target page

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, input

I performed ajax when I click a row in the table I get the answer from the server.php file with the echo inside it has  when I execute the ajax's answer to the table. I do not accept the input only the value of the input

Attaches the code

**server.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['do']) AND $_GET['do'] == "eventsclick") {

    $chkid = $_GET['id'];  
    $chk = ("SELECT * FROM eventopendrive where id = '".$chkid."'") ;
    $result = $mysqli->query($chk) ;
    $resultevent = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events where id =  '".$chkid."' ");
    $row1 = $resultevent->fetch_assoc();
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<tr class="vehicleevent'.$chkid.'" id="vehicleidnew">';
        echo '<th id="idevent" scope="row">'.$row1['id'].'</th>' ;
        echo '<td>'.$row1['date'].'</td> ' ;
        echo '<td>'.$row1['time'].'</td> ' ;
        echo '<td >'.$row1['event'].'</td> ' ; 
        echo '<td>'.$row1['location'].'</td> ' ;
        echo '<td>'.$row1['evendun'].'</td> ' ;
        echo '<td><input class="inputevent bg-light"  type="text" value="'.$row['vehicle'].'" disabled></td>';
        echo '<td><input class="inputeventtime bg-light" id="drivestart" type="text"  value="'.$row['timestart'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input class="inputeventtime bg-light" id="driveplace" type="text"  value="'.$row['timeplace'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input class="inputeventtime bg-light" id="drivecontrol" type="text"  value="'.$row['timecontrol'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input class="inputeventtime bg-light" id="driveend" type="text"  value="'.$row['timeend'].'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input class="inputeventtime bg-light" id="drivestation" type="text"  value="'.$row['timestation'].'"></td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';       

    }

    }
```

**js**

```
$('.select tr').one('click' , function (event) {
        var elID = $(this).attr('id');
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr"); 
        var col1=currentRow.find("th:eq(0)").text();
        $.get ("/server.php?do=eventsclick"  , "&id="+col1 ,
        // {
            // idfromopen : col1
        // } , 

         function(data,status){


      $("#"+elID).after(data);


    });
    });
```

**this is my output code in HTML**

```
  <tbody class="select">
  <tr clsss="trevent" id="idevent1"><th  id="idcell" scope="row">1000</th><td>23/04/2020</td> <td>14:09:04</td> <td >אזעקת אש</td> <td>במחלקת עובדים ליד המטבח</td> <td>2</td> </tr><tr clsss="trevent" id="idevent2"><th  id="idcell" scope="row">1002</th><td>23/04/2020</td> <td>14:09:04</td> <td >שריפת דירקה</td> <td>במחלקת עובדים ליד המטבח</td> <td>3</td> </tr>  
        <div id="loading" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">מעדכן אירוע...</span>
        </div>



  </tbody>
```

As you see what I got is code without input.

Many thanks to all the assistants

**Edit**
Friends I found the fault.
The problem was that the function that needs to enable the input should be after receiving the data in ajax
I would love to but another question.
Clicking on the line opens the data I want Once I click the same line again, the data will close

Tnx

Comment: Is `"&id="+col1 ` the data or part of the url as `"/server.php?do=eventsclick&id="+col1`?

Comment: Is part of the url . Tnx i fix it now.